# AngularJS $cookies 1.6.9 not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I'm using AngularJS $cookies 1.6.9 to manage cookies on my website.
I've tried a simple cookie set, as follows:

```
$cookies.put('myCookieTest', 'test');
var cookie = $cookies.get('myCookieTest');
console.log(cookie);
```

I've installed angular-cookies correctly and no error is returned in the console when I set or retrieve the cookie. Though the result of this code snippet is `undefined`. In the Google Chrome inspector, unde the Application tab, in the cookies section I don't see my cookie so it seems the code doesn't set it.

Any idea on what I'm missing here or what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you injected `ngCookies` in your module?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you injected `ngCookies` in your module and your controller. Please check this simple **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npa2y4kc/)**  and compare it with your solution. Also ensure that you are using the right version of `ngCookies`. ngCookies `1.6.9` was made for AngularJS version `1.6.9`.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller("Ctrl1", function($$cookies) {
  $cookies.put('myCookieTest', 'test');
  var cookie = $cookies.get('myCookieTest');
  console.log(cookie);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### please check version

Hi,

I think you have configured all things well but might be version issue.